# wp_get_attachment_metadata is empty

Tags: attachments

We have a website with images that do not contain any attachment metadata. I set out to create my own function that checks if there is metadata, and if there is not any, it will create it.

Unfortunately, I am afraid that `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` stays empty all of the time. Or that I can't update the metadata with `wp_update_attachment_metadata()`

My function is as followed:

```
function custom_attach_func($attch_id) {
    $meta_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attch_id);
    if($meta_data == ''){
        $attachment_path = get_attached_file($attch_id);
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attch_id, $attachment_path);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
        return $attach_data;
    }else{
        return wp_get_attachment_metadata($attch_id);
    }
}
```

While `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` does generate the metadata, and `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` returns `true`,  `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` keeps returning `''`.

Is this a Wordpress bug? Am I doing it wrong?!

Comment: Why `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );`? Are you outside of WordPress? Could you provide code and step by step guide to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @cybmeta this was needed to let `wp_generate_attachment_metadata ` work properly, check the codex under `notes` for this. This function is being called while injecting data to the post's content with `add_filter ('the_content', 'insertData');`

Comment: That is why I ask about the enviroment where you are using the code; you only need to include core files manually in some rare conditions. Can you describe the enviroment? Other than that, your code seems ok and **empty string is a valid value returned `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`**, because the value of a meta field can be a empty string.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with describing the environment. It is being run with the `add_filter ('the_content', 'insertData');` from the main plugin file. So it, I think, full within WordPress. It a regular Linux based (apache) webserver...

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough, I mean where, when and how the code is executed. As it is, the problem can not be reproduced with the given code and explanation. For example, when do you exectue `custom_attach_func()`? What is the value of `$attch_id` variable and how do you pass it to `custom_attach_func()`? Is it an attachement post type? And so on .... You can [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/241866/edit) to add more information.